# post_class not working with css

Tags: css, page-template, post-class, codex

through the codex I read about how to use the post_class() function to create a css hook for styling the content.

Here is the code I have, PHP:

```
<li class="<?php post_class();?>"> <?php the_title(); ?> </li>
<p class="<?php post_class(); ?>"> <?php the_content(); ?> </p>
```

However, the following CSS does not work, the styling does not change:

```
.category-blockquote {
color: green;
}
```

This is despite the codex saying you can prefix a category name with 'category-' in your CSS to hook onto that content.

https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/post_class

Any help on why my code is not working would be much appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, `<?php post_class(); ?>` function prints a string that contains html `'class'` attribute. So, whenever you are using this function inside class attribute, then you are actually printing another class attribute inside class attribute. That's why your class is not working.

Secondly, since `<?php the_content(); ?>` function may contains `<p>` tag, that's why never use `<?php the_content(); ?>` function inside `<p>` tag. That will break your style that you wrote for `the_content` block. Instead `<p>` tag, use `<div>`.

So, you may try with this:

```
<li <?php post_class();?>><?php the_title(); ?></li>
<div <?php post_class(); ?>><?php the_content(); ?></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is wrong:

```
<li class="<?php post_class;?>"> <?php the_title(); ?> </li>
```

That is, this-- `post_class`-- is wrong. `post_class()` is a function. What you have written is going to get you a, most likely, "undefined constant" `Notice` and won't work.

Secondly, that is not really the way `post_class()` is used. Add `post_class()` to your outer post wrapper, without the `class=` part which is generated by `post_class()`, not to individual elements in the post. What you are doing is going to add the same classes to both the `li` and the `p` which is going to cause trouble properly targeting individual pieces of the layout and will also generate a lot of unnecessary markup. For example:

> ```
> 13    <article id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class(); ?>>
> 14            <?php twentyfourteen_post_thumbnail(); ?>
> 15    
> 16            <header class="entry-header">
> 17                    <?php if ( in_array( 'category', get_object_taxonomies( get_post_type() ) ) &&
> ```
>
> twentyfourteen_categorized_blog() ) : ?>
>       18
>
> https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.9.1/src/wp-content/themes/twentyfourteen/content.php#L13

Now you would use something like:

```
.category-abc .entry-header {
   background:red;
}
```

To target `<header class="entry-header">`.

Yes, `category-{category_name}` should work:

> ## Category
>
> Category template files and pageviews displaying posts feature the class selectors: post post-id category-ID category-name
>
> http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/post_class

But the "name" will be the slug not the human readable name-- that is "abc-def" and not "Abc Def".

Comment: HI s_ha_dum, thanks for the reply. I have corrected the missing() but still, no styling is applied. Thank you for your recommendation regarding the CSS, but even trying applying the class to an outer wrapper does not fix the problem - do you know why it won;t work?

Comment: It's ok I have worked it out. class= was being duplicated as I was writing in, then calling the post_class function which also echoes class=